# Multiple input.event triggers on single button press caused by Mouse or Gamepad Joystick movement in Godot 3.2.3

Tags: input, event-handling, mouse, godot, gamepad

I'm building a game in Godot and I am running into an issue where Input.is_action_pressed, Input.is_action_just_pressed, and Input.is_action_just_released are all triggering multiple times if the mouse or gamepad joysticks are moving while clicking the buttons. I have tried checking for is_echo, but nothing registers as an echo.

I am looking for input via:

```
func _input(event):
    if Input.is_action_just_released("AttackRange"):
        fireGun()
```

This is very easily repeatable for me right now. All I have to do is move my mouse around while clicking, or moving either of the joysticks on the gamepad while pressing buttons. I can't figure out what is causing this. Should I be listening for inputs in a different way?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you are mixing ways to get input.

Either use `_input` and process only the input you get in the event parameter. *This is usually better for pointing input (mouse or touch).*

Or put your code in `_process` (or `_physics_process` if necessary) and use the `Input` object.

In this particular case, I'd move the code you have to `_process`.